# Segmentation fault while inserting in Binary search tree

Tags: c++, class, data-structures, binary-search-tree, pass-by-reference

I am trying to build a basic Binary search tree in C++ and running into some problems, specifically when I try to insert a node via function and read, it gives me segmentation fault. But the same node struct works perfectly fine when I manually insert it.
The code for BST insert is as follows, and is most likely the culprit:

```
void BST::insert(Node* temproot,int val){
  // std::cout << root->value <<std::endl;
  if(!temproot){  
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->value = val;
    temproot = newNode;
    std::cout << "Added Node with Value: " << val << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  if(val<(temproot->value)){
    std::cout << "LEFT" << std::endl;
    insert(temproot->left, val);
  }else{
    std::cout << "RIGHT" << std::endl;
    insert(temproot->right, val);
  } 
}
```

The node structure looks like this:

```
struct Node{
  int value;
  Node* left = nullptr, *right = nullptr;
};
```

And the BST class looks something like below:

```
  class BST{
  public:
  Node* root= new Node;
    BST(int val){      

      root->value = val;
    }
    void insert(Node*,int val);
    void insertStart(int vasl){
      Node* temproot = root;
      insert(temproot, vasl);
    }
    void print(Node*);
    void _print(){
      print(root);
    }
};
```

When I try to print it as follow, it gives me segmentation fault:

```
void BST::print(Node* temp){
  std::cout << temp->value << std::endl;
  temp = temp->left;
  std::cout << (temp->value) << std::endl;
}
```

I am a bit new to C++ and am having struggle pin pointing it for couple of days. Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you aware that `temproot` passed to `insert` is *a copy* of the original pointer, and the original pointer is not modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function deals with a copy of the passed to it pointer to node. So changing a copy does not influence on the original pointer.

You have to pass a pointer to node to the function by reference.
The function declaration can look the following way

```
void insert(Node* &temproot,int val);
```

and call it like

```
void insertStart(int vasl){
  insert( root, vasl );
}
```

without an intermediate pointer.

And you should declare this function as a provate static function of the class.

And initialize the data member root by nullptr.

For example

```
  class BST{
  public:
  Node* root = nullptr;

    BST(int val){      

      insert( root, val );
    }
    void insertStart(int vasl){
      insert( root, vasl);
    }
    void print(Node*);
    void _print(){
      print(root);
    }

private:
    static void insert(Node* &,int val);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, SEGFAULT comes from `print` function which should look like this:

```cpp
void BST::print(Node* temp){
    if (nullptr == temp) {
        return;
    }

    print(temp->left);
    std::cout << temp->value << std::endl;
    print(temp->right);
}
```

And your `insert` function should look like this:

```cpp
void BST::insert(Node *&temproot,int val){
    if(nullptr == temproot){  
        Node* newNode = new Node;
        newNode->value = val;
        temproot = newNode;
        return;
    }
    if(val < (temproot->value)){
        insert(temproot->left, val);
    }else{
        insert(temproot->right, val);
    } 
}
```

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMRABWABykADqgWE6rR6hiaCfgFqdDZ2jkYubpyKypiqQQwEzMQEIcam5koqUbQZWQQxDs6uHt4Kmdm5YUl1ZRVxCVwAlIqoBsTIHADkUgDMtsiGWADU4iM66nXEmMxGs9jiAAwAgptbiwaqU/YYmOIA7LLbU9dTtgRTAG5sBqcjl1s3RycAVFPsVPdZgARKa0AysVg%2BAhkKbfYh4YAIQEjEFgiFQ4izd7nIFY3a7CbMBQKKbSBgAFXO7x8BicrDwyBAu0%2Bxywv2IqFQyNRmAA7l8sHirjcyeSIHdHmxOlTPtdmbLrhyuQBaNZPQyYGYoyWsIUfG44%2BXXB6oPDoW60JTZCCszDfKQANnI9B10reRsepvNtitjHqBHFLqeClY0ouHs%2BPtcAaVBFIkpDbven0NwuNXqmPnh9BtPyTHpNZqmAH0s3cIGHkwrM9mY5yCPm0zMzrjtob3W3toXzaKQCAo9bbbDHQRMEYs/Xnfd1ZWPXgqBA0ZDoVrcdrR%2BPY5W5U2WT9QXyh8CD/zbXrqyfbaqRth1S9Vzrz9WNxOuQ%2B7Lyzx39Qq6ug%2B2gBjIjosw6DMkiSFs6BYOaQ68oQCBTAAas8HDgZIWogXMOqYaBUx/n2li6t%2BF5LAQfS0E%2BcotnOC7qphUwQC%2BsbXreqGdLOu43ARKC9MBeFSJIVjYAAYpSEG4dhPFEVRsoDgGzH1qx/xxq6sk4soShUhG3EEP%2BvFAZJYGCQASgAkgA4gAEuJGGgXh0naMRVYKvJTFjq%2BBCsfCiKqTO6ktjMbY0Z2WzdqSFJ9mWOa2r8L6cT%2BtxUIxS4Yqux7xc2LmymRFEBa2OxNtFCkecpmAAo2iU8YB/HYS%2BrF3pq9lSXphFObJxXueO3kIkilWpoVWwSkYzC2BWWUeqKUxOHUECcJVnwzQQAB08mlNakj9U2S3LaWtYVnqHq5cQtBTBsh0toM3SsCAgzuIMpCmIMGwPagt0gTIcj4b0/RNZIIycA9BC3S9HGkAA1iA3AOstZyeJ47icJwZzcAAnCM3BnJITo3YM3APU9L2kG9gwPQoIAbKQwPPVdpBwLAMCILx454OwZAUBAaAs2zIDAKj5hUKzo7EOTEBOCDD1OLYWQAJ63YDpBc0YWgEAA8rQrByzTpBYCNojsBLOt4EsaQPJg5Pa5gAAeqRAUMRN3Mohv0k4xCy3oWDy0D8JGF73Q0PQTBsBwPD8GYQgiGIchyEIeAzfA3SoFCQQW8qf7AhIn0yMjZMpGkGgQJYjSmEklhtFUiS%2BP4gR0MX4TV8U5fxNUzR58U605PoeSCIUqTt/6TcdM0/p18PrS2JUzeJN0Cg/QMXRCLd92PYbJNW54DrKg63BTMAyDIFMqPLRhEC4IQJDgQD8Z6NzriX5tUwfbIMhAxLYOQ%2B4GzLTwn/uCMDoOlRgjOG3B3CLzxg9X2n8V7axJmTCmVM3500ZhAJAfEaRxg5lzHwrNqjmEwPgIglcA6MBYAbUOvI3Y%2BD9uA5ehNXq3VGBheCBBELr03tvXe%2B9D7H1fjTMGCBlhYDcBWcB%2BNSBQMpvQ4mt14GU2pqDboH8RjHyRtweGkhP4OncJIM4IwwG4xGATVesjEH8OurdSQxjYGmIUVdboZsRZBChkAA%3D)

Comment: I try to do it manually cause it was causing errors, the actually print function is just like the one you have described above. The one mention here is just cause I have been trying to debug the issue.

Comment: @PriyankTrivedi anyway, the `print` function you showed is incorrect